# Specify component's parts as it's children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to place my React component inside DOM like this:

```js
<Table>
    <FirstNameColumnHeader>First Name</FirstNameColumnHeader>
    <LastNameColumnHeader>Last Name</LastNameColumnHeader>
    ...
    <FirstNameRowContent>John</FirstNameRowContent>
    <LastNameRowContent>Doe</LastNameRowContent>
</Table>
```

Where `Table` is something like this:

```js
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{ CONTENT OF FirstNameColumnHeader }</th>
            <th>{ CONTENT OF LastNameColumnHeader }</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{ CONTENT OF FirstNameRowContent }</td>
            <td>{ CONTENT OF LastNameRowContent }</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So it'd like to effectively filter children of `Table` component of specific type, and then I'd like to render them in specific places inside my component.
Is it any way to do it in React in elegant way. The best I came up so far is to use a context provider inside `Table` and consume it inside child components.

```js
const DataTableContext = createContext({});
const useDataTableContext = () => useContext(DataTableContext);

const Table = ({ children }) => {
    const [firstNameColumnHeader, setFirstNameColumnHeader] = useState(null);

    return (
        <DataTableContext.Provider value={{ setFirstNameColumnHeader }}>
            {children}

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{ firstNameColumnHeader }</th>
            ...
        </DataTableContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const FirstNameColumnHeader = ({ children }) => {
    const { setFirstNameColumnHeader } = useDataTableContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        setFirstNameColumnHeader(<>{children}</>);
    }, []);

    return null;
};
```

It looks clunky, and stores a JSX component inside a state, which I read is a bad practice. Is there a better way to achieve what I want? I feel like I'm trying to approach this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are ways to achieve what you're going for, but I would encourage you to consider WHY you want to do this. If the goal is to make a flexible, reusable table component, there are many available and you can always still roll your own. This format you've decided on is going to make this component structure difficult to maintain and even more difficult for humans to understand. The table structure in HTML is already pretty straightforward -- rows and cells. Why not maintain that consistent structure and have your custom components render TDs?

```
<Table>
  <Row>
    <FirstNameCell />
  </Row>
</Table>
```